# How to get count "approved replies" by laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

// I get the following error:
Error Exception in Builder.php line 2345: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::replies() (View: d:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\resources\views\homepost.blade.php)

//I tried to get count of( approved replies) in view as following but this is not work with me !!

In View:

```
 @if($posts)
        @foreach($posts as$post)

<p>No. approved replies={{$post->comments()->replies()->whereIsActive(1)->count()}}</p>
 <p>No. category={{$post->category()->count()}}


        @endforeach
    @endif
```

In Post controller:

```
       public function index()
       {
            $posts=Post::all();
            return view('Admin.posts.index',compact('posts'));
       }
```

In Post model:

```
        <?php

            namespace App;
            use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

           class Post extends Model
        {

            protected $fillable=[
                'title','body','category_id','photo_id'
            ];

            public function user(){
                return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
            }

            public function category(){
                return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
            }

            public function comments(){
                return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
            }
        }
```

In Comment model:

```
    <?php

    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Comment extends Model
    {

        protected $fillable=[
            'post_id',
            'photo',
            'author',
            'email',
            'body',
            'is_active'
        ];
        public function replies(){
            return $this->hasMany('App\CommentReply');
        }
        public function post(){
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
        }
    }
```

In CommentReply model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CommentReply extends Model
{
    protected $fillable=[
        'comment_id',
        'is_active',
        'author',
        'photo',
        'email',
        'body'
    ];

    public function comment(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Comment');
    }

}
```

Comment: Define "is not work with me!!". Do you get errors?

Comment: Incidentally, your posts have a `belongsTo` relationship on category. The count for that relationship will never be greater than one.

Comment: **Yes** I get error

Comment: ErrorException in Builder.php line 2345: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::replies() (View:)

Comment: OK, that's because replies is a relationship on each individual comment. You can't do `comments()->replies()` in the manner you're attempting. I'd personally restructure your database to put everything in `comments`, and have the replies just be comments with a `parent_id` or a `in_reply_to` or something like that.

Comment: @ceejayoz **My Data Base** what should I do in DB and relations functions?

Comment: Why aren't you using migrations?

Comment: @ ceejayoz already I used migration but i prefer show you database structure?

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('photo_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('is_active')->default(0);
            $table->string('author');
            $table->string('photo');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();


            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts')->onDelete('cascade');
           
        });

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('comment_replies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('comment_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('is_active')->default(0);
            $table->string('author');
            $table->string('photo');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->text('body');
            $table->timestamps();


            $table->foreign('comment_id')->references('id')->on('comments')->onDelete('cascade');
        });

Comment: public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

Comment: My suggestion remains: ditch the `comment_replies` table. Have replies be in the `comments` table with a `parent_id` or something like that.

Comment: @ ceejayoz what about changes in relation functions in models?

Comment: @ceejayoz can you try this ? Not sure about the query, but you will get the idea...
`$post->comments()->with(['replies'=>function($query){
 $query->selectRaw('*,count(*) as total_active')
   ->where('is_active',1)
   ->groupBy('comment_id')
}])
->selectRaw('*,sum(replies.total_active) as total')
->value('total');`
let me know of the results...

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$post->comments()
->join(DB::raw('(Select comment_id,count(*) as total from CommentReply where is_active = 1 group By comment_id) as replies'),function($join){
    $join->on('comments.id', '=', 'replies.comment_id')
})
->selectRaw('sum(replies.total) as total_comments')
->get('total_comments');
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'groupBy comment_id) as replies on `comments`.`id` = `replies`.`comment_id` where' at line 1 (SQL: select sum(replies.total) as total_comments from `comments` inner join (Select comment_id,count(*) as total from CommentReply where is_active = 1 groupBy comment_id) as replies on `comments`.`id` = `replies`.`comment_id` where `comments`.`post_id` = 4 and `comments`.`post_id` is not null)

Comment: ok.. just change `groupBy` to `group by`.. i didn't notice... updated the answer

Comment: @ jaysingkar Method value does not exist. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\resources\views\homepost.blade.php)

Comment: Method value does not exist. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\resources\views\homepost.blade.php‌​

Comment: Already i updated my code but show me  method value not exist what should I do?

Comment: What do you mean $join (method value) and this is value not exist

Comment: but I have already removed the value method in update.. could u please post your error SS

Comment: OK .I updated my code and i don't get error but show me on page the following:[{"total_comments":null}]

Comment: ok.. just use var_dump() to see the result structure.. or if possible send me your code I will make the required changes or team viewer